# Leaflet and Ordance Survey Open Data: mapping on a web page

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapping, mapbox

I am using the **UK Ordnance Survey** sample code to investigate using OS maps on a webpage with **Leaflet**.

Using the **APIKey** version works as expected and the maps render (based on the sample code provided by OS).  However, as this is insecure I am trying to get the **OAuth2 Token** version to work and it is behaving very weirdly.  The coordinates bear no relation to the real world (neither OS National Grid nor Lat/Long pairs) and the rendering style 'breaks' when using the standard 3857 SRS.  I can get the style to work properly if I change the projection to the UK/OS 27700 but the coordinates still are very strange.  If I centre the map on Trafalgar Square in London, which works with APIKey version, the map ends up in the middle of the North Sea for the OAuth Token version.

The sample code illustrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OS Vector Tile API | Basic Map (EPSG:3857) | Leaflet</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://labs.os.uk/public/os-api-branding/v0.2.0/os-api-branding.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.css" />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://labs.os.uk/public/os-api-branding/v0.2.0/os-api-branding.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mapbox-gl-leaflet/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<script>

    var apiKey = 'APIKEY FROM OPEN DATA ACCOUNT';  
    var token = 'WVqhoNsoc9D0AGDGYQ0A46tnu9nu';  //THis is generated elsewhere for simplicity

    var serviceUrl = 'https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts';

    // Initialize the map....swap these coordinates below to see how one works and not the other 
    //center: [ 51.508, -0.1281 ],  API Key version centres properly, but not the token version
    //center: [ -50,-30 ],  //These coordinates with the Token roughly centre in SW London

    var mapOptions = {
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 15,
        center: [ -50,-30 ],
        zoom: 7,
    };

    var map = L.map('map', mapOptions);

    // Load and display vector tile layer on the map.

// Uncomment this block for the API Key version
    /*var gl = L.mapboxGL({
        style: serviceUrl + '/resources/styles?key=' + apiKey,
        transformRequest: url => {
            return {
                url: url += '&srs=3857'
            }
        }
    }).addTo(map);
    */

//Uncomment this block for the OAuth2 version and also change the SRS to 3857 to see the problem
    var gl = L.mapboxGL({
        style: serviceUrl + '/resources/styles',
        transformRequest: url => {
            return {
                url: url += '?srs=27700',
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }                                
            }
        }
    }).addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Using the simple sample code above (toggling the block comment to allow for the API Key version or the OAuth2 token version, can anyone explain what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: From skimming that code it would appear the issue is not with the token but instead with the use of two different SRS'. I'd suggest splitting the question into two separate ones: One sorting out any difference between using srs=27700 and srs=3857. From memory the use of anything other than EPSG:3857 with the Leaflet MapboxGL plugin is not recommended. The other question should then deal with any issues around the token use if that is indeed still an issue after that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments - the OAuth 2 Token and map coordinates are two completely separate things...

However you access the maps tiles (using API key or OAuth 2 Token) - the `mapOptions` will be exactly the same. Most web mapping libraries will expect [by default] to have coordinates specified using latitude and longitude (and `center: [ 51.508, -0.1281 ]` will locate you in London).

In terms of access the mapping endpoints using an OAuth 2 Token - the following will probably be of help: https://github.com/tmnnrs/os-data-hub-oauth2-api